# How to use Jest's assertion library without using the Jest test runner?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

[Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) creates this global called [`expect`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#content). How can I use that *without* using their test runner? i.e., what do I have to import/require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module is simply called `expect`

e.g.

```
import expect from 'expect'

expect(1 + 1).toBe(2)
```

You can see it in the [Jest lerna repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/package.json) and the [individual package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect)

Comment: What's the difference between `expect` and [`jest-matchers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-matchers)? That's what I ended up using and seems to define all the same methods. It doesn't appear to be in their Lerna repo though, so I don't even know where it comes from.